# String not breaking into new links in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I currently have a string that is already separated into different lines using "\n". However, when I display it in a `<p>` it is not working

I have `<p>{mess}<p/>` and the thing displayed is not breaking into new lines at all.

How should I fix this?

When I first received the string I have to process it using `` so I can not add `<br />` into it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with css you can fix it, try to use:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

pre-line preserves \n as new line

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Good luck!